# Convert Binary File int32 to float32

Tags: python

I need to convert a binary file int32 to a binary file float32. The software I need to use only accepts binary floating data files.

The code I'm using is this:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.fromfile('pocobe4_r19_v18_r20.dat', dtype=np.int32).astype(np.float32)
with open("prueba_out", "wb") as prueba_out:
    prueba_out.write(array.tostring())
```

This code generates a binary file, however how can I confirm that this new binary file is float32?

How can I confirm that the int32 binary file was converted to float32 in a correct way?

Comment: What does "binary file" mean in this context? All files, when you get right down to it, are composed of ones and zeroes.

Comment: "tostring" makes me suspect that this code writes text to a file, not binary values.

Comment: Those are data types on numpy for the values you have in the file. Please double-check your assertion about "binary" files.

Comment: I get my data using GULP

http://staff.washington.edu/corey/gulp/gulp.html#64bit

The data I get with GULP is: Power (frequency) at a given time. And according to my design are int32 signed.

Comment: Can I send my data?

Comment: I ran this code only to see the values:                                                import numpy as np

array_int32 = np.fromfile('pocobe4_r19_v18_r20.dat', dtype=np.int32)
print 'Data int32 signed:'
print array_int32
array_float32 = np.fromfile('pocobe4_r19_v18_r20.dat', dtype=np.int32).astype(np.float32)
print 'Data float32:'
print array_float32

Comment: And the result is: Data int32 signed:
[-1582119980      262146           0 ...,           0           0
           0]
Data float32:
[ -1.58211994e+09   2.62146000e+05   0.00000000e+00 ...,   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]